# For a UA Revived rogue, when using Cunning Action to Dash, is there a minimum amount of movement needed to trigger Bolts from the Grave?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, rogue, unearthed-arcana

I am playing a Rogue with [The Revived](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-RuneSwarmRevived.pdf#page=4) archetype from [Unearthed Arcana (UA): Fighter, Ranger, and Rogue](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-RuneSwarmRevived.pdf). One of the Revived rogue's 3rd-level features is **Bolts from the Grave**, which procs (triggers) *immediately* after using Cunning Action:

> You have learned to unleash bolts of necrotic energy from within your revived body. **Immediately after you use your Cunning Action**, you can make a ranged spell attack against a creature within 30 feet of you, provided you
> haven’t used your Sneak Attack this turn. You are proficient with it, and you add your Dexterity modifier to its attack and damage rolls. A creature hit by this attack takes necrotic damage equal to your Sneak Attack. This uses your Sneak Attack for the turn.

An example scene:

I'm in an open space and my party and I are fighting a Hill Giant. It throws a rock at me and I get badly damaged. I decide I want to drink a potion, but still try to cause damage using my Bolts from the Grave.

I want to use my action to drink my potion, and then my bonus action to use Cunning Action (Dash), but *I don't want to move far*. In fact, I would quite happily stay where I am, but maybe just move 5 feet, or less if possible.

So:

When using the Dash option of the Cunning Action feature, is there a minimum amount of movement needed to trigger Bolts from the Grave?

Or could I just move one foot or even one inch, so that I can trigger my Bolts from the Grave attack?

Answer (score 12):

### Taking the Dash action doesn't force you to move

The [Dash](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Dash) action merely states:

> When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers. With a speed of 30 feet, for example, you can move up to 60 feet on your turn if you dash.
>
> Any increase or decrease to your speed changes this additional movement by the same amount. If your speed of 30 feet is reduced to 15 feet, for instance, you can move up to 30 feet this turn if you dash.

Nothing here forces you to move, only that you *can* move further if you wish to. And, of course, [Cunning Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#CunningAction-345) doesn't force you to move either, since all it says is that you can do so as a bonus action.

### What if my DM houserules otherwise?

You can instead use your Cunning Action bonus action to [Disengage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Disengage), which simply prevents the enemy from making an opportunity attack. You don't have to move when you take that action, and since you've used your Cunning Action, it satisfies the requirements for using Bolts from the Grave.

Comment: If the DM rules otherwise, you could always move 5 feet, then move another 5 feet back to the original position.

Answer (score 5):

### [Dash](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Dash)

> When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers. With a speed of 30 feet, for example, you can move up to 60 feet on your turn if you dash

Your movement increases. You don’t have to use any of your movement.